# Query records but return grouped by odd date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2016 to integrate with PowerBI for a static dashboard.

I have a historical table with a couple hundred thousand records in it and I need to pull data out.  The data needs to be extracted out by a category type and grouped to give me a count of that type which is easy to do but each of these records has a date associated with it and I want to show counts by group for reoccurring date ranges for a historical pull.  The problem I am having is my date ranges need to be from 7/1/{year} to 6/30/{year} as that is our annual cycle.  I know how to pull this out by a defined specific year but not when the years overlap like this.  The results I need to see are:

```
Count     Category    Year
400       Event1      2017-2018
244       Event2      2018-2019

etc.
```

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Jayson

Comment: Subtract 6 months from the dates and then extract the year for grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract 6 months and extract the year to get the fiscal year:

```
select category,
       concat(year(dateadd(month, -6, datecol), '-', year(dateadd(month, -6, datecol)+1),
       count(*)
from t
group by category, year(dateadd(month, -6, datecol);
```